# Upgrade warning when starting MariaDB

Tags: upgrade, mariadb-10.3

When I start up my Mariadb instance I see the following with systemctl:

```
$systemctl status mariadb
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-09-13 12:54:26 EDT; 13s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 38645 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-upgrade (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 38329 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-prepare-db-dir mariadb.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 38304 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 38302 ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 38367 (mysqld)
   Status: "Taking your SQL requests now..."
    Tasks: 44 (limit: 23225)
   Memory: 389.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           └─38367 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr

Sep 13 12:54:24 S-XM-DB3.my.domain mysql-prepare-db-dir[38329]: Database MariaDB is probably initialized in /var/lib/mysql already, nothing is done.
Sep 13 12:54:24 S-XM-DB3.my.domain mysql-prepare-db-dir[38329]: If this is not the case, make sure the /var/lib/mysql is empty before running mysql-prepare-db-dir.
Sep 13 12:54:24 S-XM-DB3.my.domain mysqld[38367]: 2023-09-13 12:54:24 0 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.35-MariaDB-log) starting as process 38367 ...
Sep 13 12:54:26 S-XM-DB3.my.domain mysql-check-upgrade[38669]: The datadir located at /var/lib/mysql needs to be upgraded using 'mysql_upgrade' tool. This can be done using the following steps:
Sep 13 12:54:26 S-XM-DB3.my.domain mysql-check-upgrade[38669]:   1. Back-up your data before with 'mysql_upgrade'
Sep 13 12:54:26 S-XM-DB3.my.domain mysql-check-upgrade[38669]:   2. Start the database daemon using 'service mariadb start'
Sep 13 12:54:26 S-XM-DB3.my.domain mysql-check-upgrade[38669]:   3. Run 'mysql_upgrade' with a database user that has sufficient privileges
Sep 13 12:54:26 S-XM-DB3.my.domain mysql-check-upgrade[38669]: Read more about 'mysql_upgrade' usage at:
Sep 13 12:54:26 S-XM-DB3.my.domain mysql-check-upgrade[38669]: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/sql-commands/table-commands/mysql_upgrade/
Sep 13 12:54:26 S-XM-DB3.my.domain systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.3 database server.
```

However when I run `/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade -u myadmin -p` I see this:

```
This installation of MariaDB is already upgraded to 10.3.35-MariaDB.
There is no need to run mysql_upgrade again for 10.3.35-MariaDB.
You can use --force if you still want to run mysql_upgrade
```

I've restarted mariadb several times. What gives? How do I get this warning/error to go away on startup?

Comment: Could it be that you have two installations of MariaDB?

Comment: No, I only have one. However, they are in a Galera cluster. Does that matter?

Comment: Some troubleshooting ideas [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1607926)